# HTML/CSS: Problem with full width

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at this page:
http://uploads.dennismadsen.com/fullwidth.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="da-DK">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#e0e0e0;color:#fff;">

  <div style="position:absolute;width:100%;">
      <div style="background-color:#000;">
        <div style="width:800px;margin:0px auto;text-align:right;">Container width a width of 1500px</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The inner div has a width of 800px and should be horizontal centered if the window is bigger than 800px. Try to see the page in a browser window smaller than 800 px. For instance with a width around 500px. Than the black background is not having full width when you scroll right. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<div style="background-color:#000;">` is inside `<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;">`, which width equals the width of the screen. So, `<div style="background-color:#000;">` width also equals the width of the screen. As right this div sets the black background, the background width also equals width of the screen, not more. So it does not extend to the right.

**UPDATE**

You can use just two divs:

```
<div style="background-color:#000;">
    <div style="width:800px;margin:0px auto;text-align:right;">Container width a width of 1500px</div>
</div>
```

Sorry, does not work either. Leaving it here as a non-working sample for reference.

**UPDATE 2**

And now the working variant:

```
<div style="background-color:#000;min-width:800px;width:100%">
  <div style="width:800px;margin:0px auto;text-align:right;">Container width a width of 800px</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works :)

```
<body style="background-color:#e0e0e0; color:#fff;">
    <div style="position:absolute; width:100%;">
        <div style="background:#000; width:800px; margin:0px auto; text-align:right;">Container width a width of 1500px</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please see my example here: http://uploads.dennismadsen.com/fullwidth2.html

It is not working. The container with the text should only have a width of 800px, right. But the black background should take up the hole space from left to right no matter how width the window is.

Comment: Does this work? This will only work for if it is situated at the top won't it because since there is no div with a relative position, the absolute positioned div will relate itself to the browser window won't it? So if he tries to put this in say the middle of the page, it won't work... I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I entirely understand the question, but what I think you are asking about is centering the object without it getting smaller than 800 px. What I would do is make a container div and then the internal div:

```
<div style="width:100%; min-width:800px; background-color:#000;">
    <div style="background-color:#fff; width:800px; margin:auto;">
    </div>
</div>
```

With the first div being the container that stretches the whole length of the screen, but does not get smaller than 800px, the second div being the div in question, with a set width of 800px and having the margin set to auto should make it center in the container div.

Comment: Naturally you could change the color of the backgrounds for both divs, say you wanted no background for the internal div and white text on the black background you could just delete the background color in the internal div and add a style for the text.